# Design to separate client API from internal API in Kotlin for a chess engine

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, kotlin, chess

This is a follow-up from my [previous review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239613/design-that-avoids-undesired-dependencies-in-kotlin-for-a-chess-engine) on this site. To be clear, the code is stand-alone, and does not depend on the previous review.

As before my goal is to come up with a design for a chess engine in Kotlin that hides implementation details, and that ensures that the implementation cannot accidentally become spaghetti.

## Example client code

```
package chessapp

import chessapp.api.internal.createBoard
import chessapp.api.internal.createSearchEngine

fun main() {
    val board = createBoard("1R/1p w")
    val searchEngine = createSearchEngine()
    val move = searchEngine.findBestMove(board)
    println(move)
}
```

## Client facing public API

```
package chessapp.api

enum class PieceColor { BLACK, WHITE }
enum class PieceType { PAWN, ROOK}
data class ColoredPiece(val pieceColor: PieceColor, val pieceType: PieceType)
interface Board {
    val pieces: List<ColoredPiece>
}
interface SearchEngine {
    fun findBestMove(board: Board): String
}
```

Intended to be clean and easy to understand, but bad for performance.

## Inward facing API

```
package chessapp.api.internal

import chessapp.api.Board

internal const val BLACK_PAWN: Byte = (0x00 + 0x01).toByte()
internal const val WHITE_ROOK: Byte = (0x08 + 0x05).toByte()
internal interface InternalBoard: Board {
    val bytePieces: ByteArray
    fun doInternalMove(from: Int, to: Int)
}
```

Intended to be optimized for performance and potentially hard to understand.
Additionally, the interface is likely volatile and can change quickly, which should not affect the public API.

## Implementation that supports both public and internal API

```
package chessapp.api.internal

import chessapp.api.Board
import chessapp.api.ColoredPiece
import chessapp.api.PieceColor
import chessapp.api.PieceType

fun createBoard(fen: String): Board = InternalBoardImpl(fen)
internal fun createInternalBoard(board: Board): InternalBoard = InternalBoardImpl(board as InternalBoardImpl)

internal class InternalBoardImpl(override val bytePieces: ByteArray) : InternalBoard {
    constructor(fen: String) : this(byteArrayOf(BLACK_PAWN, WHITE_ROOK)) {}
    constructor(rhs: InternalBoardImpl) : this(rhs.bytePieces.copyOf()) {}

    override val pieces: List<ColoredPiece>
        get() = bytePieces.map { it.toColoredPiece() }

    override fun doInternalMove(from: Int, to: Int) {}
}

internal fun Byte.toColoredPiece() = when (this) {
    BLACK_PAWN -> ColoredPiece(PieceColor.BLACK, PieceType.PAWN)
    WHITE_ROOK -> ColoredPiece(PieceColor.WHITE, PieceType.ROOK)
    else -> null
}!!
```

As you may notice, there is a hidden assumption that a `Board` will always be  an `InternalBoard`, and even more, implemented as an `InternalBoardImpl`. As yet I haven't figured out how to do that better without sacrificing the separation of the public and internal interface. So please feel free to comment.

## Search engine implementation that uses only the internal interface

```
package chessapp.api.internal

import chessapp.api.Board
import chessapp.api.SearchEngine

fun createSearchEngine(): SearchEngine = OptimizedSearchEngine()

internal class OptimizedSearchEngine: SearchEngine {
    override fun findBestMove(board: Board): String {
        // Intended to be badly readable code just because it is supposed to be optimized for speed
        return listOf(Pair(7, 8), Pair(7, 15)).map {
            val newInternalBoard = createInternalBoard(board)
            newInternalBoard.doInternalMove(it.first, it.second)
            Pair(evaluate(newInternalBoard), it)
        }.maxBy { it.first }?.second.toString()
    }
    private fun evaluate(internalBoard: InternalBoard) = 42
}
```

## Final words

I'd appreciate any thoughts you may have how this example design code can be improved.

To be honest, I'm not pleased with the hidden assumption that a `Board` has to be an `InternalBoard`, which in turn has to be an `InternalBoardImpl`. It goes against the OO concept that an interface should be able to have different implementations.